# Vite react proxy sends requests to different endpoints depending on current location

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, vite, node-http-proxy

After switch to vite, I am trying to mimic `proxy: "http://localhost:5000"` which I previously used in `package.json`

Here is my vite config

```js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "http://localhost:5000",
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

I have react app running on port 3000. When I send a request in the root url (`http://localhost:3000`) everything works fine

`const { data } = await axios.get("api/user/me");`

- Well, not really fine. Even though proper data is returned in response, in the console request gets sent to `http://localhost:3000/api/user/me` instead of `http://localhost:5000/api/user/me`. Can anyone explain this behaviour?

The main problem is that when I navigate to another page (e.g. `http://localhost:3000/dashboard`), then the same request gets sent to `http://localhost:3000/dashboard/api/user/me`.

What am I doing wrong? I want to send requests to `http://localhost:5000`, no matter the location

I found a workaround by specifying FE url before every request `const { data } = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/user/me");`, but still is there a way to mimic `package.json` proxy behaviour?

Comment: For your main problem of running the code on a dashboard url or somewhere else, just use an absolute path: `axios.get("/api/user/me")`.

Comment: "*in the console request gets sent to `http://localhost:3000/api/user/me`*" - that sounds normal: that's the current origin. I don't know vite, but if that is a **server** configuration, I'd expect the *server* that runs at `localhost:3000` to proxy the request - the client doesn't care.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved the issue by changing axios defaults

```js
axios.defaults.baseURL = `http://localhost:5000`
```

By doing this I achieved what I was going for. Requests get sent to the proper endpoint no matter the location

Comment: Where do I add this?  First time user of VITE

Comment: I suggest the top-level component (App.tsx | jsx), so that this change takes affect before other components are rendered

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue and I menage to solve with absolute path in axios call like this: **axios('/api/user/me')**. Before that I configure Vite in vite.config.js like this:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

//https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:5001/',
        changeOrigin: true,
      },
    },
  },
})
```

For some reason my server can't start at port 5000 that's why I set port to 5001.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem by using Axios.

1. Create a new file. I called mine `emailApi`.
2. Setup your axios, like so:

   ```
   export const emailApi = axios.create({baseURL: "http://localhost:<yourPortNumber>"})
   ```
3. Done! Whenever you want to send a request to your server, import the `emailApi` and you're good.

Also in your server, make sure to install *cors* and set it as a middleware, like so:

```
express().use(cors({origin: <viteLocalServer>}))
```

Comment: How is this different to the answer OP already posted almost a year ago? Also, if you're using a reverse-proxy, you don't need CORS